# Data Binding not working for User Control's custom Property with Dependency Property (Output window is clean)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

Note: I am not having problem with controls inside User Control like other similar articles on StackOverflow, I am having with a Property of the User Control itself. I am making a Custom Control based on Canvas, with a Dependency Property (using propdb template):

```
public sealed partial class PresentationViewer : Canvas
{

    #region Properties

    public ISlide PresentationSlide
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Get PresentationSlide");
            return (ISlide)GetValue(PresentationSlideProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Set PresentationSlide");
            SetValue(PresentationSlideProperty, value);
            this.ShowSlideContent();
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PresentationSlide.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PresentationSlideProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(PresentationSlide), typeof(ISlide), typeof(PresentationViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion

    // Other codes...
}
```

In my Page, I use the control and bind that property:

```
    <views:PresentationViewer x:Name="PresentationViewer" PresentationSlide="{Binding CurrentSlide, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

This is how I set the Page's `DataContext`:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
        this.DataContext = this.ViewModel;
    }
```

And this is the code of my `MainPageViewModel`:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // Other codes...

    public ISlide CurrentSlide
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CurrentPresentation?.Slides[this.CurrentSlideIndex];
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OpenSlide(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0)
        {
            index = 0;
        }

        if (index > this.TotalSlides - 1)
        {
            index = this.TotalSlides - 1;
        }

        this.currentSlideIndexField = index;

        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.CurrentSlideIndex)));

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Current Slide notified");
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.CurrentSlide)));

        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.PageCounter)));
    }

}
```

Notice the line where I print the notification of `CurrentSlide` property change. However, no setter or getter of the User Control's property is called. Here is the output when `OpenSlide` is called (the output is since the beginning of the program):

[image]

The Binding is already in two-way mode. And other control in my page (Label, etc...) are also notified and changed their content, such as the Page counter, so I guess it is not the ViewModel problem too. Am I missing something in my Custom Control class? How can I make the Binding work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.100).aspx), the CLR wrapper of a dependency property may not be called, so your breakpoints aren't hit and the `ShowSlideContent` method isn't executed. Instead, the framework directly calls the dependency property's `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods.

> Because the current WPF implementation of the XAML processor behavior
>   for property setting bypasses the wrappers entirely, you should not
>   put any additional logic into the set definitions of the wrapper for
>   your custom dependency property. If you put such logic in the set
>   definition, then the logic will not be executed when the property is
>   set in XAML rather than in code.

In order to react on changed property values, you'll have to register a `PropertyChangedCallback` with property metadata:

```
public ISlide PresentationSlide
{
    get { return (ISlide)GetValue(PresentationSlideProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PresentationSlideProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty PresentationSlideProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(PresentationSlide),
        typeof(ISlide),
        typeof(PresentationViewer),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, PresentationSlidePropertyChanged));

private static void PresentationSlidePropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((PresentationViewer)o).ShowSlideContent();
}
```

Or, with a lambda expression:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PresentationSlideProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(PresentationSlide),
        typeof(ISlide),
        typeof(PresentationViewer),
        new PropertyMetadata(null,
            (o, e) => ((PresentationViewer)o).ShowSlideContent()));
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much for the reference link. I used `propdb` from a UWP article, so I didn't know about this at all.