# Binding to a custom control in edit mode

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

In a grid I have a column like this that uses a custom control that changes to a text box when in edit mode.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn
    CanUserSort="True"
    Header="HelpMeStuckOnThis" 
    Width="Auto"
>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TeachersList, Converter={StaticResource ListConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />

        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ourControls:MyScheduleEntry ScheduledValue="{Binding Path=DefaultServiceKey, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But when I set the value of `DefaultServiceKey` in code behind, it never hits the SET method of my `ScheduledValue` dependency property in that custom control.

Which makes me think it never hits the binding , but why?
As far as datacontext goes, I know that the `TeachersList` part is working and both `TeachersList` and `DefaultServiceKey` are properties on the object.

Comment: When a dependency property is set by a Binding (and some other sources), WPF bypasses the setter of the CLR property wrapper and directly calls `DependencyObject.SetValue`. You should register a PropertyChangedCallback with dependency property metadata to get notified about property changes. See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37383050/1136211).